Modifying a last element of a list-column in dplyr
I have a tibble where one of the columns is a vector list with equal length. I want to replace the last element of the list column with the maximums (by positions) of all vectors.
Eg.
my_tibble <- tibble(a = list(c(2, 4, 10, 10, 10), c(1, 12, 4, 8.5, 14), c(1,3,9, 15, 11)), b = c("a", "b", "c"))

I want to replace the last element of column a with the maximums of all three elements by positions. The last list element of a should now be
c(2, 12, 10, 15, 14)

How do I do this in a dplyr pipe? My all attempts using purrr::map  so far have failed and I don't think I am even getting closer. Any help is appreciated.

Do you want something like:
library(dplyr)

my_tibble |>
  mutate(a = replace(a, row_number() == length(a), list(do.call(pmax, a))))

# A tibble: 3 × 2
  a         b    
  <list>    <chr>
1 <dbl [5]> a    
2 <dbl [5]> b    
3 <dbl [5]> c  

Where my_tibble$a is:
[[1]]
[1]  2  4 10 10 10

[[2]]
[1]  1.0 12.0  4.0  8.5 14.0

[[3]]
[1]  2 12 10 15 14


Maybe dplyr isn't that useful here.
my_tibble$a[[nrow(my_tibble)]] <- do.call(pmax.int, my_tibble$a)

With purrr
library(purrr)
my_tibble$a[[nrow(my_tibble)]] <- reduce(my_tibble$a, .f = \(x,y) if_else(x < y, y, x))

data.table::transpose
my_tibble$a[[nrow(my_tibble)]] <- data.table::transpose(my_tibble$a) |> map_dbl(max)

